# How can I prevent a API call from being timed out

Tags: javascript, dom

Im trying to call my Backend API using jquery, and I did set the timeout to a very high amount but my request keeps stopping after sometime. My API takes anywhere between 1 min to 7 mins to process the request but the API request keeps returning "We couldn't connect to our API, please check your network or contact support" when the API call takes more than 2 or 3 mins. Any code improvement and workaround would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my Code

```
function upgrade() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 10000000 //Time in milliseconds
});
load();
$.getJSON("https://example.com", function(data) {
    if (data.success == true) {
        console.log("s");
    }
    else if (data.success == false) {
        console.log("f");
    }
    stopload();
})
.fail(function() { 
    console.log("We couldn't connect to our API, please check your network or contact support");
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value of 0 means there will be no timeout. Please try giving timeout as 0.